# How do I extend a class that is not public on my framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, class, frameworks

I have built an iOS framework but now I'm refactoring it and I want to make some of the classes private so the users don't use it anymore (I don't want them to call some inner APIs directly).

The problem is that one of the public classes extends a class that is now private. The code of my ContentLoader.h file was like below:

```
#import <ImageX/Loader.h>

@interface ContentLoader: Loader

// methods and stuff

@end
```

If I leave it like this and try to build, the compiler complains that "**ImageX/Loader.h file not found**" because now it is set as "**Project**" on the **Target Membership** settings. If I change it to "**#import "Loader.h"**", then it builds the framework but when I load it on my sample app that uses it, the app doesn't build because it can't find the Loader.h file.

How do I solve this issue without setting the Loader.h file to public again?

Answer (score 0):

first thing to address is wether you are actually using that class (Loader.h) in ContentLoader header or not ? because if not then just include it in .m where you use it, but if you actually use it in the .h then just dont bother look into this the Loader.h has to be public, however you can "delete" some on the content that s present in Loader.h using a ruby script during the build of the framework, but it has to be something that s not present in ContentLoader.h (or .m if that s public)
for example suppose there s a function in Loader.h called "-(void)someFunction;", and you use it (or overrride it in your case) in your .m here s how to delete it from Loader.h to it wont be seen by anyone using the framework after you build it:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/-(void)someFunction\n//g' "pathtoyourfile/Loader.h" > "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/Loader2.h"

cp "pathtoyourfile/Loader2.h" "pathtoyourfile/Loader.h"

rm "pathtoyourfile/Loader2.h"
```

and finally just put those line as a script in build phases

Comment: The only use of the Loader.h is because the ContentLoader class inherits some properties that the Loader implements. Is it fine to just remove the ": Loader" from my ContentLoader class interface after building it?

Comment: nah it wont work that way, well it might , but in general terms it wont, what I mean by that , that maybe in your specific case it will but generally speaking it wont